# How to use Meteor Accounts.changePassword()

Tags: javascript, meteor, passwords

I am confused. I have this little piece of code.

```
Accounts.changePassword($scope.tmp.oldPassword, $scope.tmp.newPassword, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("failed changing password", error);
  } else {
    console.log("success changed password");
  }
});
```

`$scope.tmp.oldPassword` and `$scope.tmp.newPassword` are plain text. The code runs without any problems logging `success changed password`. But in the end the password isn't changed. Do I have to do anything else? Like update the user, encrypt the passwords or something?

Comment: Ah well sorry. I don't get any errors. But I found the problem. Right after changing the password I updated the user (changed other data too). That overwrote my changed password...of course. Thanks for the direction ;).